# Is transmitting digital data just like transmitting voice signals?

Tags: license, ionosphere

I would like to find a free shortwave frequency and start transmitting digital data ( from 1 to 10 Mhz ) .
I will be just transmitting binary data for couple of hours , and i won't use it for voice-transmission purposes .

Given my needs , do i still need a Ham license or is the law more generous in this case ?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: i live in italy

Comment: @AlessandroMini https://www.mise.gov.it/images/stories/documenti/radio/PNRF_27_maggio_2015.pdf

Comment: In USA there are "no license required"  frequencies , unfortunately I do not remember the official title. Something about "experimental / medical use ..." My guess would be such frequencies will be available in Italia.